# Regex to count the total number of words in a string

Tags: javascript

The total number of words in this string is 11. But my code returns 13.

```
var txt = "Helllo, my -! This is a great day to say helllo.\n\n\tHelllo! 2 3 4 23";
txt = txt.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
var words_count = txt.match(/\S+/g).length;
```

Comment: What's your definition of a `word`?

Comment: Are the double-double-quotes intentional? (`""`)

Comment: (["helllo","my","this","is","a","great","day","to","say","helllo","helllo"] is 11 words)

Comment: i put double-double quotes by mistake

Comment: But `sayhelllo` is a single word in the input. Is that a typo too?

Comment: sorry. I am new.  Did a lot of typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\S+` will match any non-space character, which will include substrings like `-!`. You might match sequences of non-space characters which also include at least one alphabetical character in them, with `\S*[a-z]\S*`:

```js
var txt = "Helllo, my -! This is a great day to sayhelllo.\n\n\tHelllo! 2 3 4 23";
console.log(txt.match(/\S*[a-z]\S*/gi).length);
```

If you can count on what you want to count as a "word" to start with an alphabetical character, you can remove the leading `\S*`.

If you want to make the trailing `\S*` more restrictive, you could whitelist a list of permitted characters inside "words", like `'` if you want:

```js
var txt = "Helllo, my -! This is a great day to sayhelllo.\n\n\tHelllo! 2 3 4 23";
console.log(txt.match(/[a-z][a-z']*/gi).length);
```

(to add more characters to the whitelist, just expand the `[a-z']` character set to whatever you need)